# bash_completion for Rails 3

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-3, bash-completion

Is there any `bash_completion` script ready for Rails 3?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I wrote this one https://github.com/jweslley/rails_completion

> Bash completion support for Ruby on Rails.
>
> The completion routines provide support for completing:
>
> - rails commands (e.g.: new, server, console, generate, runner, ...)
> - rails generators (e.g.: scaffold, controller, mailer, observer, ...)
> - rails environments
> - rails field's types on generators (e.g.: scaffold, model, migration, ...)
> - common --long-options...

Comment: Thanks, but when I type: `rails c<Tab><Tab>` I get error: `_get_comp_words_by_ref: command not found`

Comment: Ok, I haven't bash-completion installed... now it's ok! Thanks!

Comment: that's awesome.  any idea how hard it would be to adapt it for use from zsh?

Answer (score 4):

Nice https://github.com/jweslley/rails_completion is also wrapped with Brew.

Perform:
`brew install rails-completion`
on your Mac to install it in seconds!

And don't forget to add `.rails_generators~` to `.gitignore`.